# Recreate filter() function using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

We have to recreate the `filter()` function using recursion.

I have the following:

```
def even(X):
    if X % 2:
        return True
    return False

def myFilter(f, L):
    return f(L[0]) + myFilter(f, L[1:])
```

When I try to run: `print (myFilter(even, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))`, I get an error saying `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Could someone point me in the right direction to fix this please?

**note:** We cannot use any built-in python functions

Comment: Are you really trying to replicate `filter`, or `map`? That is, should the result be a list of Boolean values (the return values from your `even` function) or should the result be the values from the original list that make `even` return `True`?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, your even function is backwards... it returns True for odds and False for evens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the base case:

```
def even(X):
    if not X % 2:
        return True
    return False

def myFilter(f, L):
    if not L:
        return []
    return [f(L[0])] + myFilter(f, L[1:])

>>> myFilter(even, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
[True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
>>> myFilter(even, [])
[]
>>> myFilter(even, [2])
[True]
>>> myFilter(even, [1])
[False]
```

Comment: Thank you for not using built-in functions

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have correctly identified that the issue causing your exception is the lack of a base case. When your `myFilter` function is called with an empty list, it can't access `L[0]`.

However, they don't address the fact that you're not actually filtering at all, rather you're doing the same operation as the builtin `map` function. If you really want to filter, you need to operate a little differently.

```
def myFilter(f, L):
    if not L:
        return []  # base case, fixes the exception

    if f(L[0]):  # use the return value of f to tell whether to include L[0] in return
        return L[0] + myFilter(f, L[1:])
    else:
        return myFilter(f, L[1:])
```

If you didn't have to use recursion, a more Pythonic (and more efficient) way of doing the same thing would be to use a list comprehension:

```
def myFilter(f, L):
    return [x for x in L if f(x)]
```

If you haven't learned list comprehensions yet, its essentially the same as this unpacked version:

```
def myFilter(f, L):
    result = []
    for x in L:
        if f(x):
            result.append(x)
    return result
```

The nice thing about these versions is that they don't need an explicit base case. If the list `L` is empty, the `for` loop will simply not do anything, resulting in an empty list being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your recursion finally ends up with a list of length 0. Thats why accessing `L[0]` does not work here.

```
def my_filter(callback, let):
     if len(lst) == 0: 
         return []
     return ([lst[0]] if callback(lst[0]) else []) + my_filter(callback, lst[1:])
```

Note that `f(L[0]) + myFilter(f, L[1:])` won't work, since myFilter should return a list and f(L[0]) is a boolean.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have a recursion stopping condition. try this:

```
def even(X):
    if X % 2:
        return True
    return False

def myFilter(f, L):
    if (len(L) == 1):
        return f(L[0])
    return f(L[0]) + myFilter(f, L[1:])
```

Answer (score -1):

You should define end of recursion condition:

```
def even(X):
if X % 2:
    return True
return False


def _filter(f, l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return [l[-1]] if f(l[-1]) else []
    else:
        return filter(f, l[:-1]) + ([l[-1]] if f(l[-1]) else [])

print(_filter(even, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 6]))
```